# Can’t get the shader function to work correctly on an etch a sketch - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I’m currently doing the Odin project and trying to get the etch a sketch working. Have been going okay until I ran into the shader type brush.. for some reason it’s only shading the top left, ie. very first div I created in the grid.

https://chealkin.github.io/etchasketch/etcha.html

Code is below;

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

/*  END OF RESET */

body {
  background-color: #DEDEDE;
}

#mainContainer {
  width: 720px;
  height: 720px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 0;
  border: 5px #CDCDCD solid;
}
button {
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 27px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 17px;
  color: #5F6368;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 11px 4px;
  min-width: 54px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
button:hover {
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #fff, #e8e8e8);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #fff, #e8e8e8);
  color: #222;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
#black {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30%;
  top: 3%;
  -ms-transform: translate(10%, 5%);
  transform: translate(10%, 5%);
}
#shader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 36%;
  top: 3%;
  -ms-transform: translate(10%, 5%);
  transform: translate(10%, 5%);
}
#rgb {
  position: absolute;
  left: 43%;
  top: 3%;
  -ms-transform: translate(10%, 5%);
  transform: translate(10%, 5%);
}
#erase {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 3%;
  -ms-transform: translate(10%, 5%);
  transform: translate(10%, 5%);
}
#reset {
  position: absolute;
  left: 57%;
  top: 3%;
  -ms-transform: translate(10%, 5%);
  transform: translate(10%, 5%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Etchasketch</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <button id="black">Black</button>
  <button id="rgb">Random</button>
  <button id="erase">Eraser</button>
  <button id="reset">Reset</button>
  <button id="shader">Shader</button>
  <div id="mainContainer"></div>


  <script>
    let blackBrush = document.querySelector('#black');
    let rgbBrush = document.querySelector('#rgb');
    let eraseBrush = document.querySelector('#erase');
    let resetButton = document.querySelector('#reset');
    let shaderBrush = document.querySelector('#shader');
    var currentBrush = 'rgb';

    blackBrush.addEventListener('click', () => {
      currentBrush = 'black';
    });
    rgbBrush.addEventListener('click', () => {
      currentBrush = 'rgb';
    });
    eraseBrush.addEventListener('click', () => {
      currentBrush = 'erase';
    });
    shaderBrush.addEventListener('click', () => {
      currentBrush = 'shade';
    });
    resetButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      let x = prompt('How many sections would you like in each row?')
      resetGrid(x);
    })

    function createGrid(number) {
      //      size = (size < 4) ? 4 : (size > 64) ? 64 : size;
      let gridSize = number;

      for (let i = 0; i < gridSize ** 2; i++) {
        const container = document.querySelector('#mainContainer');
        const row = document.createElement('div');
        container.appendChild(row);
        row.id = 'grids';
        row.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        row.style.opacity = '1';
        row.style.width = getSize(gridSize);
        row.style.height = getSize(gridSize);
        row.verticalAlign = 'top';
        row.style.display = 'inline-block';
        row.onmouseover = function() {
          return row.style.backgroundColor = getColor();
        };
      }

    }

    function getSize(x) {
      let size = (720 / parseInt(x));
      return size + 'px';
    }

    function resetGrid(x) {
      let container = document.getElementById('mainContainer');
      while (container.firstChild) {
        container.removeChild(container.firstChild);
      }
      createGrid(x);
    }

    function getColor() {
      if (currentBrush === 'black') {
        return 'black';
      } else if (currentBrush === 'rgb') {
        return randomBrush();
      } else if (currentBrush === 'erase') {
        return 'white';
      } else if (currentBrush === 'shade') {
        getShade();
      }
    }

    function getShade() {
      var row = document.querySelector('#grids');
      if (row.style.backgroundColor === 'black') {
        return;
      } else if (row.style.opacity === 0) {
        row.style.backgroundColor === 'black';
      } else {
        row.style.opacity -= 0.1;
      }
    }

    function randomBrush() {
      var r = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255));
      var g = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255));
      var b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255));
      return 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
    }

    createGrid(16);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

If anyone could help point out what I’m doing wrong it would be hugely appreciated! TIA

Comment: Could you provide us with a [mcve]

Comment: `code is below` ... no, it's currently in a github that you'll end up changing, thus making this question pointless once you have got your answer, i.e. it'll help nobody else ever. So, put your current code in the question instead

Comment: `var row = document.querySelector('#grids');` ... ID's must be uniques in HTML ... `row` will ALWAYS be the first such element ... how do you expect javascript know which of these many elements with `id="grids"` you actually want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your code doesn't play well in snippets, (unless you go full screen with the snippet of course) but the point is that all your "pixels" have the same ID, therefore `document.querySelector('#grids')` always refers to the first one

instead, pass the element the mouse over event targets along to the code

instead of

```
row.onmouseover = function() {
    row.style.backgroundColor = getColor();
}
```

use

```
row.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    row.style.backgroundColor = getColor(e.target);
});
```

then in `getColor`, accept an argument to pass on to `getShade`

```
  function getColor(grid) {
     ....
      } else if (currentBrush === 'shade') {
        getShade(grid);
      }
  }
```

then in `getShade` use `row` as the argument name, and use that

```
  function getShade(row) {
      ....
  }
```

```js
let blackBrush = document.querySelector ('#black');
      let rgbBrush = document.querySelector ('#rgb');
      let eraseBrush = document.querySelector ('#erase');
      let resetButton = document.querySelector ('#reset');
      let shaderBrush = document.querySelector ('#shader');
      var currentBrush = 'rgb';

      blackBrush.addEventListener('click', () => { currentBrush = 'black'; });
      rgbBrush.addEventListener('click', () => { currentBrush = 'rgb'; });
      eraseBrush.addEventListener('click', () => { currentBrush = 'erase'; });
      shaderBrush.addEventListener('click', () => { currentBrush = 'shade'; });
      resetButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let x = prompt('How many sections would you like in each row?')
        resetGrid(x);
      })
      
      function createGrid(number) {
//      size = (size < 4) ? 4 : (size > 64) ? 64 : size;
        let gridSize = number;
        
        for (let i = 0; i < gridSize ** 2; i++) {
          const container = document.querySelector('#mainContainer');
          const row = document.createElement('div');
          container.appendChild(row);
          // row.id = 'grids'; //id not needed
          row.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
          row.style.opacity = '1';
          row.style.width = getSize(gridSize);
          row.style.height = getSize(gridSize);
          row.verticalAlign = 'top';
          row.style.display = 'inline-block';
          row.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
            return row.style.backgroundColor = getColor(e.target);
          });
        }

      }

      function getSize(x) {
        let size = (720 / parseInt(x));
        return size + 'px';
      }

      function resetGrid(x) {
        let container = document.getElementById('mainContainer');
        while (container.firstChild) {
          container.removeChild (container.firstChild);
        }
        createGrid(x);
      }

      function getColor(grid) {
        if (currentBrush === 'black') {
            return 'black';
          } else if (currentBrush === 'rgb') {
            return randomBrush();
          } else if (currentBrush === 'erase') {
            return 'white';
          } else if (currentBrush === 'shade') {
            getShade(grid);
          }
      }

      function getShade(row) {
        if (row.style.backgroundColor === 'black') {
          return;
        } else if (row.style.opacity === 0) {
          row.style.backgroundColor === 'black';
          } else {
            row.style.opacity -= 0.1;
            }
      }

      function randomBrush() {
        var r = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255));
        var g = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255));
        var b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255));
        return 'rgb('+ r + ', '+ g + ', ' + b + ')';
      }

      createGrid(16);
```

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

/*  END OF RESET */

body {
  background-color: #DEDEDE;
}

#mainContainer {
  width: 720px;
  height: 720px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 0;
  border: 5px #CDCDCD solid;
}
button {
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 27px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 17px;
  color: #5F6368;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 11px 4px;
  min-width: 54px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
button:hover {
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #fff, #e8e8e8);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #fff, #e8e8e8);
  color: #222;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
#black {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30%;
  top: 3%;
  -ms-transform: translate(10%, 5%);
  transform: translate(10%, 5%);
}
#shader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 36%;
  top: 3%;
  -ms-transform: translate(10%, 5%);
  transform: translate(10%, 5%);
}
#rgb {
  position: absolute;
  left: 43%;
  top: 3%;
  -ms-transform: translate(10%, 5%);
  transform: translate(10%, 5%);
}
#erase {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 3%;
  -ms-transform: translate(10%, 5%);
  transform: translate(10%, 5%);
}
#reset {
  position: absolute;
  left: 57%;
  top: 3%;
  -ms-transform: translate(10%, 5%);
  transform: translate(10%, 5%);
}
```

```html
<button id = "black">Black</button>
    <button id = "rgb">Random</button>
    <button id = "erase">Eraser</button>
    <button id = "reset">Reset</button>
    <button id = "shader">Shader</button>
    <div id = "mainContainer"></div>


    <script>
    </script>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! And sorry, I've updated my post with the code inside instead of having it on github.